# Symbols with various characters

Tags: ruby, symbols

I would like to turn strings like the following into symbols:

- `'Architects & Engineers'`
- `'Catering & Hotels'`

They have characters like `'&'`, `'/'`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I have rarely used enums in Rails, but I'd use `:architects_and_engineers` for the enum (ideally even shorter) and generate a value suitable for the dropdown via `I18n`, so the generated HTML looks like `<option value="architects_and_engineers">Architects &amp; Engineers</option>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
'Architects & Engineers'.to_sym == :'Architects & Engineers'
#⇒ true

['Architects & Engineers'.to_sym, :'Architects & Engineers'].map(&:to_s)
#⇒ ["Architects & Engineers", "Architects & Engineers"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use classy_enum gem https://github.com/AgilionApps/classy_enum

```
class YourEnum < ClassyEnum::Base
end

class YourEnum::ArchitectAndEngineer < YourEnum
  def to_s
    "Architects & Engineers"
  end
end

class YourEnum::DocterOrEngineer < YourEnum
  def to_s
    "Doctor/Engineer"
  end
end
```

then you can use it like

```
YourEnum.map(&:to_s) # ["Architects & Engineers", "Doctor/Engineer"]
```

You can find the enum like

```
YourEnum.find("Architects & Engineers") #<YourEnum::ArchitectAndEngineer:0x007f96ccb16628>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
:"Architects & Engineers"     # => :"Architects & Engineers"
:"Architects & Engineers" == "Architects & Engineers".to_sym # => true
```